# How to get row numbers and cell letters in excel?

Tags: excel

In the namebox of excel datasheet each cell corresponds to a letter-number identification e.g. C8 ----> column C, row 8
is there any function or formula to give column letter and row number for every cell ?

Comment: `=address(row(), column())` more options available at [ADDRESS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-D0C26C0D-3991-446B-8DE4-AB46431D4F89).

Comment: is possible to give separate results for row - column ? i want to give a number for "odd" rows (e.g. A, C, E , ... ) and even rows (B, D, F, ..)

Comment: these are columns, not rows. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you can use the R1C1 notation instead of A1. Excel Options > Formulas > tick R1C1 Reference style.

Answer (score 0):

Try R1C1 reference style. Excel Options > Formulas > tick the box

[image]