# Excel Formula vs Formula used in conditional format

Tags: excel-formula

I have a excel formula which correctly returns true. But when I used the same formula in conditional format, I am not able to get the conditional format. Please help.

```
=AND(FIND("MyText",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+2,COLUMN()))=1)
```

If the first cell of the column is "My-text" and the value is 1 (in row +2, same column) the formula correctly returns true. If I used it in a conditional format to paint a fore-ground color it is not working. I also tried search and searchb. But didnt work. The format of the cell (row() +2, column) that might have value 1 is "General"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the AND into following and it worked. But not sure what is the issue with AND in conditional format

> =NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("MyText",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()))))) 
>   *INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+2,COLUMN()))

Added the above answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you change to [`R1C1` reference style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604918/1383168]), you can enter the formula as `=AND(R1C="MyText", R[2]C=1)`

`R1` means row 1, `C` means same column, and `R[2]` means 2 rows below the current cell.

In `A1` reference style, the formula will depend on the currently active cell, so if for example the active cell is `A1`, the formula will be `=AND(A$1="MyText", A3=1)`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am generating my excel file by program and had to resort to address(row(), column()) approach. But yours is still a valid solution for excels created manually.

Comment: @NSN it makes no difference (unless using non-English Excel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649293/excel-vba-use-localized-rc-formula-for-conditional-formatting). Volatile functions like INDIRECT are ineficient, because they have to be re-calculated a lot more than needed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891#sectionSection2. You can use for example `INDEX(1:1, 1, COLUMN())` instead of `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()))`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this wouldn't work.  But you can simply replace the `AND` function with `*`.  Here is what you can try:

```
=FIND("MyText",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())))*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+2,COLUMN()))=1
```

Comment: Just revised my formula to make it shorter.